# Details in proof of Corollary A.10. in Hatcher. How do we embed a finite CW-complex into Euclidean space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

tl;dr: what am I missing about the proof of Corollary A.10. in Hatcher?

**Claim:** Any finite CW-complex is an ENR.

**Hatcher's proof**:
Since CW-complexes are locally contractible, it suffices to show that any finite CW-complex can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$. Induct on the number of cells. Suppose a finite CW-complex $X$ is obtained from a subcomplex $A$ by attaching $D^k$ along $f \colon S^{k-1} \to A$. By induction, we may assume that $A$ embeds into $\mathbb{R}^m$ for some $m$. Then $X$ embeds into $\mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}$ as the union of $D^k \times \{0\} \times \{0\}$, $\{0\} \times A \times \{1\}$, and all line segments joining $(s, 0, 0)$ and $(0, f(s), 1)$ for $s\in S^{k-1}$. QED.

My understanding of the conclusion of this proof is that $X$ is *homeomorphic to* $Y:= (D^k \times \{0\} \times \{0\}) \cup (\{0\} \times A \times \{1\}) \cup (\bigcup_{s \in S^{k-1}}\{(1-t)(s, 0, 0) + t(0, f(s), 1): t \in [0, 1]\})$.

**The problem:** I see an embedding $i \colon X \hookrightarrow Y$ but not a homeomorphism. Let $x \in X$. If $x \in A$, let $i(x) := (0, x, 1)$. If $x \in D^k$, write $x = ts$ for $s \in S^{k-1}$ and $t \in [0,1]$, and set $i(x) := ((1-t)x, tf(s),t)$. This doesn't seem to surject onto $Y$ (e.g. if $x = s$, then $(x, 0, 0)$ is not in the image of $i$).

What am I missing? Is there something wrong with the embedding I came up with? What embedding was Hatcher thinking of that makes $X$ and $Y$ homeomorphic?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your formula for $i : X \hookrightarrow Y$ is not correct when $x \in D^k$.

I think the nature of your error is in confusing the $D^k$ in the domain of the attaching map $f$ with the $D^k$ in the formula for $Y$. Roughly speaking, the corrected formula for $i$ will take the **half radius inner subdisc** of $D^k$ (as the domain of $f$) to the full $D^k$ (as a subset of $Y$). Also, the **half radius outer annulus** of $D^k$ will be taken to the union of line segments described by Hatcher.

Here are the details:

On the half radius disc $|x| \le .5$ define $i(x) = (2x,0,0)$, so its image is all of $D^k \times \{0\} \times \{0\}$.

On the annulus $.5 \le |x| \le 1$, for each $s \in S^{k-1}$ there is a radial segment in $D^k$ from $.5s$ to $s$, parameterized as $(.5(1-t) + t)s = (.5+.5t)s$ ($t \in [0,1]$). The map $i$ will take this to the line segment in $Y$ from $(s,0,0)$ to $(0,f(s),1)$, by the formula
$$i : (.5(1-t) + t)s  \to (1-t)(s,0,0) + t(0,f(s),1) \quad\text{for each $t \in [0,1]$}
$$

Comment: Anyway, Hatcher's $Y$ (or your $i(X)$) does not coïncide with the definition of $X$ as "the CW-complex obtained from A by attaching Dk along f" (as defined in [his chapter 0](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch0.pdf) p. 5). I guess what he had in mind in [his appendix](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATapp.pdf) p. 527-528 was rather that $X$ is not *homeomorphic* to $Y$ but is a *retract* of it (?)

Comment: @AnneBauval: I don't follow either of your comments. I am using the CW-complex $X$ and the subset $Y \subset \mathbb R^{k+m+1}$ as given in this extract of Hatcher. The question is about the correct formula for a homeomorphism $i : X \to Y$.

Comment: Apologies, I was wrong and I think I understand you perfectly now. Your $i$ is indeed a realization of Hatcher's definition of chapter 0 and represents the result as a subspace of the $Y$ of the appendix. What do you think about "X is not homeomorphic to Y but is a retract of it"?

Comment: Well, I do think $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$. But, your critique made me realize that I could better explain the nature of the OP's error; I added a new paragraph with that explanation (the 2nd paragraph in the present version).

Comment: I should have understood it sooner. Thank you.